# Логическая ошибка в коде Java

Tags: java

Этот код пример из книги "Шилдт Г. - Java 8. Руководство для начинающих".
В нём явная логическая ошибка, но я как новичок не могу заставить программу работать. Хотя в принципе понимаю в чём ошибка. Как исправить?

Код программы:

```
class FDemo {
    int x;

    FDemo(int i){
        x = i;
    }

    protected void finalize() {
        System.out.println("Финализация " + x);
    }

    void generator(int i) {
        FDemo o = new FDemo(i);
    }
}

class Finalize {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        int count;
        FDemo ob = new FDemo(0);
        for(count = 1; count < 100000; count++)
            ob.generator(count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow. "в принципе понимаю в чём ошибка" - пожалуйста, не надо темнить. Понимаете - так скажите.

Comment: `Как исправить?` исправить что?

Comment: Я пишу код в Notepad++, компилирую и запускаю из командной строки. Может ли быть в этом причина? То есть, если пример кода скопирован из какой то среды разработки? Так как по логике класс мейн должен содержатся в классе имя которого совпадает с именем файла.java который я запускаю. А в книге с определенного момента код приобрел вид как я написал в примере. Т.е. класс мейн объявляется в описании другого класса.

Comment: Я не совсем понял...... main вы можете написать хоть в каждом файле. только назначить точку входа нужно одну с определенного конкретного..

Comment: Обратите внимание что тело класса FDemo заканчивается перед описанием класса Finalize  в котором содержится метод мейн. На это и ругается при запуске машина.

Comment: Два непубличных класса в одном файле могут находится. Ничего страшного в этом нет. Ваш код работает корректно. В чем именно ваша проблема? У вас программа запускается или нет? Как вы компилируете и что получаете на выходе после компиляции?

Comment: Error: Main method not found in class FDemo, please define main method as:public static void main(String [] args).  Сообщение при запуске файла Java FDemo.class Програма компилируется без ошибок.

Comment: @Musikmaniak а почему вы его запускаете, а не Finalize? Или у вас файл называется FDemo, а внутри содержится в том числе класс Finalize?

Comment: Да, файл FDemo и внутри написан Finalize. В книге не было никаких пояснений на тот счет, кроме того что класс мейн должен содержатся в классе который совпадает с именем исполняемого файла.

Comment: Как вы компилируете?

Comment: javac FDemo.java    для запуска java FDemo.class

Comment: В результате выполнения команды `javac FDemo.java` у вас должны появиться два файла - FDemo.class и Finalize.class. Соответственно далее - `java Finalize`, и всё заработает. Без `.class`.

Comment: Да, действительно заработало. Как мне восполнить пробел  в знаниях?

Comment: У каждой программы есть входная точка - метод main. Есть случаи, когда таких методов может быть в программе несколько, в разных классах. Чтобы программа знала, где ей искать метод main нужно указать при запуске класс, именно класс, не файл, в котором находится нужный метод main. Когда программа собирается в .jar файл обычно нужный метод main прописывается в MANIFEST.MF файл.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код не гарантированно сработает, если вы добиваетесь, увидеть надпись "Финализация". GC просто не успевает запуститься и удалить созданные объекты.

Должно быть, примерно, так:

```
public class Finalize {    
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    FDemo ob = new FDemo(0);
    for (int count = 1; count < 100_000; count++)
        ob.generator(count);

    System.gc();

    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(100);
}


static class FDemo {
    int x;

    FDemo(int i) {
        x = i;
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() {
        System.out.println("Финализация " + x);
    }

    void generator(int i) {
        FDemo o = new FDemo(i);
    }
}}
```

Comment: Спасибо, мне уже помогли в комментариях. Проблема была другого характера.